# xcode throw sigabrt on every second run project

Tags: xcode, sigabrt

This is not a programmatic question, I think but I don't know where to ask it.

It starts on my current main project from nothing. I don't add or change anything, just don't work on it for a while, and when I open it and try to run in simulator all was ok, for the first time. When I click run button second time (without any changes or with it (I tried both variants)) sigabrt is appear and stop the simulation. Click run button third time – all works fine, fourth time sigabrt again and so on.

The problem exist for a new, clear project. (just add a button to storyboard) and sigabrt appear on every second run project. What I can do with this? It's some kind of xcode bug or something. Can I fix it without reinstall Xcode? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update xcode. Lion 10.8 and that version of xcode when using lldb debug crashes like that.

Apple just released the update to fix this last week.